# List all videos from all the playlists on a YouTube channel (without downloading video or audio)

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

How can I get a list of all the videos inside all the playlists on a given YouTube channel?

As in download only the titles and rest of the metadata, not the actual media files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```shell
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --write-info-json --skip-download -o "./%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvrLvII5oxSWEMEkszrxXEA/playlists
```

Explanation

- `--ignore-errors` Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist, which would stop execution of the whole command
- `--write-info-json` Write video metadata to a .info.json file
- `--skip-download` Do not download the video
- `-o "./%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s"` Output to **`First playlist title/Video number one about things.info.json`**

Answer (score 1):

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors --write-info-json --skip-download -o "./%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMjEg73ogUEJO8XFmEBOApRY0PBKSzCyB
```

Comment: please describe more what's happening with the code, result execution for example, try to describe regexp. make it more readable